# Adobe Flash camera recording with filter

Tags: flash, filter, adobe, camera, record

Imagine that you want to record video with filter you made but stream class doesn't publish video but camera and camera class doesn't have filter option. What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

To do that, the idea would be to write the video feed in a bitmapData and then apply the filter to the bitmapData

Try this code:

```
// get the cam
var video:Video; 
var camera:Camera=Camera.getCamera(); 
video=new Video(320,240); 
video.attachCamera(camera); 

// create the bitmap
var bmpD:BitmapData=new BitmapData(video.width,video.height); 
bmpD.draw(video);
var bm:Bitmap=new Bitmap(bmpD); 
addChild(bm);

// apply the filter
var bf:BlurFilter = new BlurFilter(4, 4, 3);
bm.filters = [bf];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Erwan but i couldn't express myself clearly i think. When i want to record from web camera i also want it to record filter i use with it. I mean when recording is done, i also want to see my filter on my recorded video. I wonder if there is any chance to send publish function bitmap or video not camera? or any other way to do it